# Component-based architecture vs. Distributed system

Tags: architecture, components

Can we describe a component-based architecture as a distributed system for an example EJB is a component based architecture as well as it has qualities to become a distributed system?
So how can these two concepts combine together, or to differentiate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

["Component-based"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component-based_software_engineering) means "**separation of concerns**", whether those are:

- **physical** (with **tiers**, where each "compoents" represent a physical unit of separation/deployment, like a 3-tiers architecture with a web server (1 tier) delivering web pages (another tier) which draws on data from a database the 3rd tiers. See [FinnNk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190233/finnnk)'s answer for the [question 3 Tier Architecture vs 2 Tier Architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621206/3-tier-architecture-vs-2-tier-architecture).
- **logical** (with **layers** with components representing **responsibilities**).

The term component is "generic" enough to be applied to any architecture where you can identify several concerned which can be isolated.

Hence, a [distributed system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_computing) can be viewed as a collection of physical components (the "nodes") or logical components (as for [EJB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ejb): a server-side "component", here a "model" that encapsulates the "business logic" of an application)

Answer (score 0):

In both cases you divide a system into parts.

The difference in a distributed system is that the it can be called over the wire.

You should have a look at the 4 pillars of service orientated architecture:

http://www.stsc.hill.af.mil/crossTalk/2007/09/0709LewisSmith.html